# Java generic for getting and setting multiple members from POJO

Tags: java, generics, java-8

My POJO looks like this

```
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Getter
public final TestPOJO {
    private double fieldA;
    private double normFieldA;
    private double fieldB;
    private double normFieldB;
    private double fieldC;
    private double normFieldC;
    private double fieldD;
    private double normFieldD;
    private double fieldE;
    private double normFieldE;
}
```

I have list of TestPOJO and I need to calculate the normalized value for each field. For that I have the following function

```
List<TestPOJO> setNormalizedValue(List<TestPOJO> pojos) {
    final double[][] rawValues = new double[5][pojos.size()];
    for (TestPOJO pojo: pojos) {
        rawValue[0][i] = pojo.getFieldA();
        rawValue[1][i] = pojo.getFieldB();
        rawValue[2][i] = pojo.getFieldC();
        rawValue[3][i] = pojo.getFieldD();
        rawValue[4][i] = pojo.getFieldE();
        i++;
    }
    final Pair<double[], double[]> stdPopAndMean = getStdPopAndMean(rawValues);
    final double[] stdPop = stdPopAndMean.getLeft();
    final double[] mean = stdPopAndMean.getRight();

    return pojos.stream()
        .map(p -> p.toBuilder()
                    .normFieldA(getNormalizedValue(p.getFieldA(), stdPop[0], mean[0]))
                    .normFieldB(getNormalizedValue(p.getFieldB(), stdPop[1], mean[1]))
                    .normFieldC(getNormalizedValue(p.getFieldC(), stdPop[2], mean[2]))
                    .normFieldD(getNormalizedValue(p.getFieldD(), stdPop[3], mean[3]))
                    .normFieldE(getNormalizedValue(p.getFieldE(), stdPop[4], mean[4]))
                    .build()
            )
        .collect(Collectors.toList());    
}
```

Like this but instead of just 5 field i have approx 20. Is there any way to do this via some kind of java generic loop. I tried using Supplier and Consumer but the problem was `Cannot refer to static content from non-static.`

I was thinking something like

```
private static final Map<Integer, Pair<Consumer<Double>, Supplier<Double>>> FUNCTIONS_MAP = 
    ImmutableMap.<Integer, Pair<Consumer<Double>, Supplier<Double>>>builder()
        .put(0, Pair.of(TestPOJO.TestPOJOBuilder::normFieldA, TestPOJO::getFieldA))
        .put(1, Pair.of(TestPOJO.TestPOJOBuilder::normFieldB, TestPOJO::getFieldB))
        .put(2, Pair.of(TestPOJO.TestPOJOBuilder::normFieldC, TestPOJO::getFieldC))
        .put(3, Pair.of(TestPOJO.TestPOJOBuilder::normFieldD, TestPOJO::getFieldD))
        .put(4, Pair.of(TestPOJO.TestPOJOBuilder::normFieldE, TestPOJO::getFieldE))
        .build();

        
List<TestPOJO> setNormalizedValue(List<TestPOJO> pojos) {
    for (TestPOJO pojo: pojos) {
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Pair<Consumer<Double>, Supplier<Double>>> entry : FUNCTIONS_MAP) {
            final int position = entry.getKey();
            final Supplier<Double> getter = entry.getValue().getRight();
            rawValue[position][i] = getter.get(pojo);
        }
        i++;
    }
    final Pair<double[], double[]> stdPopAndMean = getStdPopAndMean(rawValues);
    final double[] stdPop = stdPopAndMean.getLeft();
    final double[] mean = stdPopAndMean.getRight();

    return pojos.stream()
        .map(p -> { 
                TestPOJO.TestPOJOBuilder builder = p.toBuilder();
                for (Map.Entry<Integer, Pair<Consumer<Double>, Supplier<Double>>> entry : FUNCTIONS_MAP) {
                    final int position = entry.getKey();
                    final Supplier<Double> getter = entry.getValue().getRight();
                    final Consumer<Double> setter = entry.getValue().getLeft();
                    final double similarity = getNormalizedValue(getter.get(p), stdPop[position], mean[position]);
                    setter.accept(similarity); // How to set it for p
                }
                return builder.build();
                    
            }
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

But as it can be seen there are some obvious issues here. I think there should be a better solution which is eluding me. Any ways to run this on a loop?

I know this can be done via reflection but that's not what i want to do.

Edit:

```
/**
     * Calculates the mean and population standard deviation for given 2D array.
     * It will take each 1D array as a dataset and calculate the mean and std dev for that.
     *
     * @param values      2D array to calculate for.
     * @param recordCount The length of 1D array. It assumes that all rows are of same length.
     * @return A pair of std dev array and mean array where each entry corresponds to computation for each row.
     */
    public Pair<double[], double[]> getStdPopAndMean(final double[][] values, final int recordCount) {
        final double[] mean = new double[values.length];
        final double[] stdPop = new double[values.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            mean[i] = getMean(values[i], recordCount);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            double diffSquared = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < recordCount && j < values[i].length; j++) {
                diffSquared += (values[i][j] - mean[i]) * (values[i][j] - mean[i]);
            }
            final double variance = diffSquared / recordCount;
            stdPop[i] = FastMath.sqrt(variance);
        }

        return Pair.of(stdPop, mean);
    }
```

Comment: Could you provde code of `getStdPopAndMean` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Consumer<Double>` and `Supplier<Double>`, you should use `BiConsumer<TestPOJO.TestPOJOBuilder, Double>` and `Function<TestPOJO, Double>` instead. The difference is that the latter functional interfaces' function types all take an extra parameter, representing the object you want to get/set the fields of.

You'd use `getter.apply(pojo)` to get the field, and `setter.accept(builder, similarity)` to set a field of the builder.

```
private static final Map<Integer, Pair<BiConsumer<TestPOJO.TestPOJOBuilder, Double>, Function<TestPOJO, Double>>> FUNCTIONS_MAP =
        ImmutableMap.<Integer, Pair<BiConsumer<TestPOJO.TestPOJOBuilder, Double>, Function<TestPOJO, Double>>>builder()
                .put(0, Pair.of(TestPOJO.TestPOJOBuilder::normFieldA, TestPOJO::getFieldA))
                .put(1, Pair.of(TestPOJO.TestPOJOBuilder::normFieldB, TestPOJO::getFieldB))
                .put(2, Pair.of(TestPOJO.TestPOJOBuilder::normFieldC, TestPOJO::getFieldC))
                .put(3, Pair.of(TestPOJO.TestPOJOBuilder::normFieldD, TestPOJO::getFieldD))
                .put(4, Pair.of(TestPOJO.TestPOJOBuilder::normFieldE, TestPOJO::getFieldE))
                .build();


List<TestPOJO> setNormalizedValue(List<TestPOJO> pojos) {
    int i = 0;
    final double[][] rawValue = new double[5][pojos.size()];
    for (TestPOJO pojo: pojos) {
        for (var entry : FUNCTIONS_MAP.entrySet()) {
            final int position = entry.getKey();
            final var getter = entry.getValue().getRight();
            // you can pass the pojo to Function.apply
            rawValue[position][i] = getter.apply(pojo);
        }
        i++;
    }
    final Pair<double[], double[]> stdPopAndMean = getStdPopAndMean(rawValue);
    final double[] stdPop = stdPopAndMean.getLeft();
    final double[] mean = stdPopAndMean.getRight();

    return pojos.stream()
            .map(p -> {
                        TestPOJO.TestPOJOBuilder builder = p.toBuilder();
                        for (var entry : FUNCTIONS_MAP.entrySet()) {
                            final int position = entry.getKey();
                            final var getter = entry.getValue().getRight();
                            final var setter = entry.getValue().getLeft();
                            final double similarity = getNormalizedValue(getter.apply(p), stdPop[position], mean[position]);

                            // a BiConsumer takes 2 arguments, allowing you to pass the builder to it
                            setter.accept(builder, similarity);
                        }
                        return builder.build();

                    }
            )
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have collected all logic in one class.

In case you have many similar fields in `TestPOJO`, I would recommend you, to split it into a pairs smth. like `fieldX - normFieldX` and use it as mach as you have pairs in the `TestPOJO`.

But if you cannot modify this class, I think you can use reflection to get all  pairs at runtime.

```java
public final class StatisticsCalculation {

    public List<TestPOJO> setNormalizedValue(List<TestPOJO> pojos) {
        Map<String, Statistics> idStatistics = calcStat(pojos);

        return pojos.stream()
                .map(pojo -> setNormFields(idStatistics, pojo))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static Map<String, Statistics> calcStat(List<TestPOJO> pojos) {
        Map<String, Statistics> map = new HashMap<>();

        getIds().forEach(id -> {
            double[] values = pojos.stream()
                    .mapToDouble(pojo -> getFieldValue(id, pojo))
                    .toArray();
            map.put(id, calcStatistics(values));
        });

        return map;
    }

    private static List<String> getIds() {
        return Arrays.stream(TestPOJO.class.getDeclaredFields())
                .map(Field::getName)
                .filter(fieldName -> fieldName.startsWith("field"))
                .map(fieldName -> fieldName.substring(5))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static Statistics calcStatistics(double[] values) {
        return Statistics.builder()
                .sdt(Double.NaN)    // calc real value
                .mean(Double.NaN)   // calc real value
                .build();
    }

    private static double getFieldValue(String id, TestPOJO pojo) {
        try {
            String fieldName = "field" + id;
            Field field = pojo.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            return field.getDouble(pojo);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private static TestPOJO setNormFields(Map<String, Statistics> idStatistics,
                                          TestPOJO pojo) {
        TestPOJO.TestPOJOBuilder builder = pojo.toBuilder();

        for (Map.Entry<String, Statistics> entry : idStatistics.entrySet()) {
            double value = getFieldValue(entry.getKey(), pojo);
            double normValue = normalizeValue(value, entry.getValue());
            setNormFieldValue(identry.getKey() normValue, builder);
        }

        return builder.build();
    }

    private static void setNormFieldValue(String id,
                                          double normValue,
                                          TestPOJO.TestPOJOBuilder builder) {
        try {
            String fieldName = "normField" + id;
            Method method = builder.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(fieldName,
                                                                 double.class);
            method.invoke(builder, normValue);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private static double normalizeValue(double value, Statistics statistics) {
        return (value - statistics.mean) / statistics.sdt;
    }

    @Builder
    private static final class Statistics {

        private final double sdt;
        private final double mean;

    }

}
```

Client code will look like this:

```java
List<TestPOJO> pojos = List.of(
        TestPOJO.builder().fieldA(11).fieldB(21).fieldC(31).fieldD(41).fieldE(51).build(),
        TestPOJO.builder().fieldA(12).fieldB(22).fieldC(32).fieldD(42).fieldE(52).build(),
        TestPOJO.builder().fieldA(13).fieldB(23).fieldC(33).fieldD(43).fieldE(53).build());

List<TestPOJO> res = new StatisticsCalculation().setNormalizedValue(pojos);
```

---

In case you cannot or do not want to use reflection, so you can replace it with additional code:

```java
public final class StatisticsCalculation {

    public List<TestPOJO> setNormalizedValue(List<TestPOJO> pojos, List<Id> ids) {
        Map<Id, Statistics> idStatistics = calcStat(pojos, ids);

        return pojos.stream()
                .map(pojo -> setNormFields(idStatistics, pojo))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static Map<Id, Statistics> calcStat(List<TestPOJO> pojos, List<Id> ids) {
        Map<Id, Statistics> map = new HashMap<>();

        ids.forEach(id -> {
            double[] values = pojos.stream().mapToDouble(id::getFieldValue).toArray();
            map.put(id, calcStatistics(values));
        });

        return map;
    }

    private static Statistics calcStatistics(double[] values) {
        return Statistics.builder()
                .sdt(Double.NaN)    // calc real value
                .mean(Double.NaN)   // calc real value
                .build();
    }

    private static TestPOJO setNormFields(Map<Id, Statistics> idStatistics,
                                          TestPOJO pojo) {
        TestPOJO.TestPOJOBuilder builder = pojo.toBuilder();

        for (Map.Entry<Id, Statistics> entry : idStatistics.entrySet()) {
            double value = entry.getKey().getFieldValue(pojo);
            double normValue = normalizeValue(value, entry.getValue());
            entry.getKey().setNormFieldValue(normValue, builder);
        }

        return builder.build();
    }

    private static double normalizeValue(double value, Statistics statistics) {
        return (value - statistics.mean) / statistics.sdt;
    }

    @Builder
    private static final class Statistics {

        private final double sdt;
        private final double mean;

    }

    @Builder
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    public static final class Id {

        private final Function<TestPOJO, Double> getValue;
        private final BiConsumer<TestPOJO.TestPOJOBuilder, Double> setNormValue;

        public double getFieldValue(TestPOJO pojo) {
            return getValue.apply(pojo);
        }

        public void setNormFieldValue(double normValue, TestPOJO.TestPOJOBuilder builder) {
            setNormValue.accept(builder, normValue);
        }

    }

}
```

Client code will look like this:

```java
List<TestPOJO> pojos = List.of(
        TestPOJO.builder().fieldA(11).fieldB(21).fieldC(31).fieldD(41).fieldE(51).build(),
        TestPOJO.builder().fieldA(12).fieldB(22).fieldC(32).fieldD(42).fieldE(52).build(),
        TestPOJO.builder().fieldA(13).fieldB(23).fieldC(33).fieldD(43).fieldE(53).build());
List<StatisticsCalculation.Id> ids = List.of(
        StatisticsCalculation.Id.builder().getValue(TestPOJO::getFieldA).setNormValue(TestPOJO.TestPOJOBuilder::normFieldA).build(),
        StatisticsCalculation.Id.builder().getValue(TestPOJO::getFieldB).setNormValue(TestPOJO.TestPOJOBuilder::normFieldB).build(),
        StatisticsCalculation.Id.builder().getValue(TestPOJO::getFieldC).setNormValue(TestPOJO.TestPOJOBuilder::normFieldC).build(),
        StatisticsCalculation.Id.builder().getValue(TestPOJO::getFieldD).setNormValue(TestPOJO.TestPOJOBuilder::normFieldD).build(),
        StatisticsCalculation.Id.builder().getValue(TestPOJO::getFieldE).setNormValue(TestPOJO.TestPOJOBuilder::normFieldE).build());

List<TestPOJO> res = new StatisticsCalculation().setNormalizedValue(pojos, ids);
```